# Groovy: evaluate a property with a variable in it

Tags: groovy

A bit new to groovy, I am trying to match a variable string to a property pulled from a file using ConfigSlurper. I have the slurper part working fine, but can't seem to figure out the right way to evaluate a property with a variable in it. I think I was getting warm when I found [evaluating-code-dynamically-in-groovy](http://jorgemanrubia.net/2009/10/10/evaluating-code-dynamically-in-groovy/) but I am not entirely sure.

```
//properties.groovy
jobs {
  foo {
    email="foo@email.com"
  }
}

//myscript.groovy
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File('properties.groovy').toURI().toURL())

List jobs = (ArrayList) BazAPI.getArtifacts(bucket) // list of objects, foo is one
ListIterator jobIterator = jobs.listIterator();

while (jobIterator.hasNext()) {
    Object j = jobIterator.next();
    job_name = "${j.name}" //
    email = config.jobs."${job_name}".email /* NEED TO FIGURE OUT HOW TO EVAL */
    foo_email = config.jobs.foo.email //evaluates to the correct property in properties.groovy

    //these values get fed to a DSL but to illustrate
    println "${job_name}"    // prints foo
    println "${email}"       // prints [:]
    println "${foo_email}"   // prints foo@email.com
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
config.jobs[ j.name ].email
```

Comment: Quick follow up...email now equals the property or [:] if the property does not exist. How do I switch on that? I tried email.equals(null), email.empty, email.equals(':').

Comment: You could try the Elvis operator `email ?: 'na'`

Comment: Works. I can see I have a lot to learn in groovy.

  `def prop = Config.configs.jobs[ a.name.replace('-', '') ].email
  def address = prop ?: null
  if (address.equals(null)) {
   addresses = Config.DEFAULT_EMAIL
  } else {
      addresses = prop.concat(", ${Config.DEFAULT_EMAIL}")
  }`

Comment: Sorry to beat a dead horse yet again, but what is this [] notation called. I can't seem to find a reference for it and I am running into a similar situation again where I want to plug a value into a variable that I want evaluated.  

`def bucket = 'artifacts'
def static JSON_PROD_URL = "https://blahblah.it/"
def static env = 'PROD'
OVURL = new URL("JSON_${env}_URL".concat("${bucket}.json"))
result = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(OVURL.newReader())`

This yields a Caught: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: JSON_PROD_URLartifacts.json

Comment: You'll want something more like `new URL( "${this[ "JSON_${env}_URL" ]}${bucket}.json")`, but it's hard to tell from snippets of code in the comments (comments on here are awful for code) :-(

Comment: Yeah, I can't seem to find multiline code for comments.Anyway, of course, your line worked for me! and I think I see that this notation is called the index operator(?), from ch. 12.3 Dynamically Accessing Objects in Programming Groovy by Subramaniam. Thanks Tim.

Comment: There isn't a multiline code for comments. However, if you have a new question (even if it's kinda related) and you have tried to see if it is already answered, then you should feel free to post another question. As I watch moderators all over the net *cringe* when I make that suggestion, let me re-emphasize that you should *really* try to see if the question is already answered first.